# Are there any dangling pointers in my program?

Tags: c, pointers

```
char** removeDuplicateChromosomes(char* input[], int no_of_chromosomes)
{
    char** result = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char* )*(no_of_chromosomes));

    //some piece of code 
    result[count] = input[itr]; 
    //some piece of code . I didn't free any pointers here in this function

    return result;
}
```

Can someone help me to identify any dangling pointers (if present) and explain the same pls?

Comment: Don't cast `malloc`'s return value.

Comment: Note: You can write "sizeof(**input)" so that it's unambiguous why you are sizing a char*.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak - if no pointer points to unfreed memory.
Dangling pointer - a pointer that points to freed memory.

Your code has a significant risk of either / both, though without a complete code sample, it's impossible to tell whether either would occur. I'll just give some possible scenario's of when it could happen.

As an initial note, If you don't free `result`'s memory in the calling function, you'd have a memory leak. Any `malloc` must have a corresponding `free`.

**If you free `input` like this:**

```
free(input);
```

There would not be a dangling pointer.

But then there may be a memory leak if each element of `input` doesn't have an element of `result` pointing to the same memory. And if multiple elements of `result` point to this memory, you'll probably end up with a dangling pointer when you try to free it, along with some undefined behaviour.

**If you free `input` like this:**

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < inputSize; i++)
  free(input[i]);
free(input);
```

There would be a dangling pointer.

**Why?**

`input[itr];` is a pointer.

`result[count] = input[itr];` just makes `result[count]` point to the same memory as what `input[itr]` points to.

So if we free `input[itr]`, `result[count]` would point to freed memory, and thus be dangling.

If we don't free `input[itr]`, `result[count]` will still point to valid memory.

If you want `result[count]` to point to its own memory, you'll have to use:

```
result[count] = malloc(inputItrSize);
memcpy(result[count], input[itr], inputItrSize);
```

Note - there's no way to tell how much memory `input[itr]` is pointing to, so you'll have to declare `inputItrSize` with the appropriate size yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A dangling pointer is a pointer to a memory area that is no-longer allocated.

```
char* dangleMeBaby(char* obj) {
    free(obj);
    return obj;
}

int* localDangle() {
    int i = 10;
    return &i;
}

#define NUM_POINTERS 8
char** wholeLottaDangle() {
    char* ptr = malloc(sizeof(char*) * NUM_POINTERS);
    size_t i;
    void* data = malloc(NUM_POINTERS);
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTERS; ++i) {
        ptr[i] = data + i;
    }
    free(data); // all the pointers in ptr now dangle.
    free(ptr);  // and ptr itself is now a dangle
    return ptr;
}
```

If you have allocated input as one big block of pointers + data, then freeing input before result will turn result into an array of dangling pointers.

```
size_t indexSize = sizeof(char*) * numChromosomes;
size_t chromosomeSize = (MAX_CHROMOSOME_LEN) * numChromosomes;
char* data = malloc(indexSize + chromosomeSize);
char** input = (char**)data;
char* chromosome = data + indexSize;
for (size_t i = 0; i < numChromosomes; ++i, chromosome += MAX_CHROMOSOME_LEN) {
    input[i] = chromosome;
}
// no dangling pointers in result until you free input.
```

If you have allocated chromosomes individually and then allocated "input" to house all the pointers, then freeing a chromosome without removing it from "result" will cause a dangling pointer

```
result = removeDuplicateChromosomes(input, 64);
free(input[0]); // result still points to it, result is dangling.
```

But if input and the list of chromoes remain intact until you free input() and/or any chromosomes, you have no dangling pointers.